# Is it possible to set up a betfair api-ng non interactive login for android

Tags: android, api, betfair

I am trying to write an android application that will use the non interactive login to the Betfair API-NG. I am just wondering if this is possible as to do this I need to generate certificates on my computer. Will this generated certificate be ok (and work) when I copy it to my android?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the normal API Login https://api.developer.betfair.com/services/webapps/docs/display/1smk3cen4v3lu3yomq5qye0ni/Non-Interactive+%28bot%29+login